Is there casteism in Kashmir/Trika Shaivism?
Is there casteism in Kashmir/Trika Shaivism?
Also what about Shaivism as a whole?

No I think as it Trika is based on bhairava agamas. If you go by Vedic shaivism it is pretty much casteist as like any other Vedic Sampradaya.

@CracklingCyclone so, you mean to say that there isn't Casteism in Trika Shaivism but it is in other vedic ones? Which ones? Veerashaivas reject it out right, and doesn't Shaiva Siddhanta have collection of sages coming from all castes writing their works?

Not sure that is a word - casteism. There are varnas in Indian cultural tradition. "caste" is a poor translation first used by the Portugese in India.

@VedantSingh I think you are mixing up Virasaivas and Lingayats, Lingayats  reject Varnashrama Dharmam. Virasaivas adhere to it and they also have a bhashya written on Bramhasutras.
